# Get-Printer -AsJob how to find ComputerName on error

Tags: powershell, jobs

We're trying to retrieve all installed printers in bulk. For this we use the `-AsJob` switch on the `Get-Printer` CmdLet. This works fine when all `ComputerNames` exist, but when there's one that doesn't exist an error is correctly thrown.

**Example**

```
$ComputerName = @('Computer1', 'NonExisting', 'Computer2')

$GetPrinterJobs = Foreach ($C in $ComputerName) {
    Get-Printer -ComputerName $C -AsJob
}

$GetPrinterJobs | Wait-Job -EA Ignore | Receive-Job
```

This code will throw one error for the `NonExisting` ComputerName. How is it possible to see that the error is actually coming from ComputerName `NonExisting` ?

> Get-Printer : The spooler service is not reachable.  Ensure the
>   spooler service is running.

With the help below from @JosefZ this is **solved** as following:

```
$GetPrinterJobs = Foreach ($C in $ComputerName) {
    $C
    Get-Printer -ComputerName $C -AsJob
}

$null = Get-Job | Wait-Job -EA Ignore

$GetPrinterJobResults = for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $GetPrinterJobs.Count; $i += 2 ) {

    $ReceiveParams = @{
        ErrorVariable = 'JobError'
        ErrorAction   = 'SilentlyContinue'
    }
    $ReceivedJobResult = $GetPrinterJobs[$i + 1] | Receive-Job @ReceiveParams

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ComputerName = $GetPrinterJobs[$i]
        State        = $GetPrinterJobs[$i + 1].State
        Data         = $ReceivedJobResult
        Error        = if ($JobError) {
            $JobError
            $JobError.ForEach( { $Error.Remove($_) })
        }
    }
}

$GetPrinterJobResults
```

Comment: I'm currently on Windows7, so I cannot test this myself, but wouldn't it be easiest to wrap the `Get-Printer` inside an `if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $C -Count 1 -Quiet) { Get-Printer -ComputerName $C -AsJob } else { Write-Error "Computer '$C' is either off-line or does not exist." }` ?

Comment: I can't test this but could you use a try/catch block in the foreach loop so that you could return the current object (computername) and the error?

Comment: @Theo a machine can be online but the spooler service might not respond, So your proposal wouldn't work in that case.

Comment: @I.TDelinquent Try/Catch doesn't work as we wait for all job results at the same time. Otherwise it would defeat the purpose of using jobs.

Comment: @DarkLite1 good point :)

Comment: @DarkLite1 - instead of using jobs ... why don't you use `Invoke-Command` with the computer list in the `-ComputerName` parameter to run the scriptblocks on the remote machines in parallel? that will let you get your data faster and won't bog down the system that is running the main script. you can either capture the errors in `-ErrorVariable` OR compare the result list with the input list to find the non-responders.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey That's a great idea but doesn't work. The thing is, `Get-Printer` doesn't require remoting/admin permissions on the remote machine while `Invoke-Command -ComputerName` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my *old-school* workaround:

```
$ComputerName = @('Computer1', 'NonExisting', 'Computer2')

$GetPrinterJobs = Foreach ($C in $ComputerName) {
    $C
    Get-Printer -ComputerName $C -AsJob
}

$GetPrinterJobResults = $GetPrinterJobs | 
    Where-Object { $_.GetType().Name -ne 'String'} | 
        Wait-Job -EA Ignore | Receive-Job

for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $GetPrinterJobs.Count; $i+=2 ) {
    @{
        $GetPrinterJobs[$i] = $GetPrinterJobs[$i + 1].State
    }
}
```

Should return something like

```
Name          Value                                               
----          -----                                               
Computer1     Completed                                           
NonExisting   Failed                                              
Computer2     Completed
```

Comment: Awesome! This really solved it for me so thank you very much. I'm gonna edit my question to reflect how I used your code to retrieve the error with the correct `ComputerName`.